# zf3 - calling custom plugin from Module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'm new to Zend Framework 3. And migrating my Zend Framework 2 application to Zend Framework 3.

Currently I'm trying to call `userPlugin` from Application Module's `Module.php` file.

Here is my code,

```
public function onRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $userPlugin = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('userPlugin');
    $userPlugin->setServiceManager($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager());
    $checkLogin = $userPlugin->isLoggedIn();
}
```

And in my `module.config.php`,

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    //This is also not working
    //'invokables' => array(
    //    'userPlugin' => 'User\Controller\Plugin\UserPlugin',
    //),
    'factories' => [
        Controller\Plugin\UserPlugin::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'userPlugin' => Controller\Plugin\UserPlugin::class,
    ]
)
```

But getting this error

> Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by the name "UserPlugin" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Where am I wrong?

Comment: ZF3 might be a bit more strict about your aliases. I'm not sure at all! You registered it without a capital letter, while your module.php is calling: "UserPlugin". It would be nicer to use the FQCN as in: `->get(\MyModule\Controller\Plugin\UserPlugin::class)` instead of `->get('UserPlugin')`. Could you check if that is working?

Comment: @Kwido I have tried with you solution also. But not worked for me.

Comment: Can you show `Module.php` class or how do you attach to `route` event? Also, does your plugin work in controller?

Comment: The error message and code relating to the `->get('userPlugin')` do not match up. "UserPlugin" (in error message) is not "userPlugin" (as shown in your example). @Kwido is correct, [In ZF3 this will cause you an issue as the service names are literal strings](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-servicemanager/migration/#case-sensitivity-and-normalization). Are you sure you are using `->get('userPugin')` and not `->get('UserPlugin');`.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code

```
 $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
 $checkLogin = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')
                  ->get(Controller\Plugin\UserPlugin::class)
                  ->isLoggedIn();
```